# How to use filterBy method in Extjs store for array

Tags: extjs

I'm using Ext.js 4.1 version. I have created a dataview (tpl) using below json data . What i want is to filter the associatedElementsDetails field with "host" and "policyDetails" .

```
{
    "category": "Hosts Under Maintenance",
    "associatedElementsDetails": [ 
        {
            "host": "windows",
            "policyDetails": [
                {
                    "policyName": "test",
                    "status": "active",
                    "policyTimeLine": [
                        {
                            "date": "Mar 09, 2016-Mar 10, 2016",
                            "time": [
                                {
                                    "timeperiods": "18:41-18:41"
                                },
                                {
                                    "timeperiods": "00:41-18:41"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "date": "Daily",
                            "time": [
                                {
                                    "timeperiods": "00:00-12:00"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "policyName": "test1",
                    "status": "active",
                    "policyTimeLine": [
                        {
                            "date": "Daily",
                            "time": [
                                {
                                    "timeperiods": "00:00-23:59"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How to filter the "host" and "policyTimeLine" using filterBy method of the store?

Answer (score 0):

You can use filterBy(fn, [scope])
For example:

```
msgStore.filterBy(function (record){
    if (record.get('host') && record.get('policyDetails')) {
    // do something
        return true;
    }
    return false;

});
```

Comment: My model will be like this Ext.define('category', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     fields: [
      {name: 'category',  type: 'string'},
      {name: 'associatedElementsDetails', type: 'array'},
      {name: 'heading', type: 'array'},
     ]
    }); How can i get record.get('host') && record.get('policyDetails')

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to create store

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    model: 'your model',
    storeId: 'your model id',
    proxy: {
         type: 'ajax',
         url: 'myurl.json',
         reader: {
              type: 'json',
              root: 'people'
         }
    }
});
```

Then use store manager lookup

```
var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('Your store');
var filter= new Ext.util.Filter({
    filterFn: function(item) {
        //do filter

    }
});
```

http://existdissolve.com/2011/11/extjs-4-filtering-on-multiple-fields/